# Code does not run if inside folder named "js"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file called analytics.js containing this code:

```
console.log('test')
```

I'm calling the code right before the ending body tag in my index.html, like this:

```
<script src="/vendors/analytics/js/analytics.js"></script>
```

The code does not run. However, if I change the folder name to "asdf" the code WILL run. Like this:

```
<script src="/vendors/analytics/asdf/analytics.js"></script>
```

What on this good earth is going on??

Comment: Are you sure you can access to the script file in "/vendors/analytics/js/analytics.js" from your browser?

Comment: first place your js file to asdf folder then make sure its linked correctly after that try a hard refresh ... some time its happens..  best of luck

Comment: Maybe it's the spy-blocker of the browser ..?

Comment: @teemu is probably right, if you have some sort of ad blocker on or anything blocking tracking/analytics, it is recognizing the folder of `js/analytics.js`. The best solution would probably be either rename the file or rename the folder.

Comment: Did you tried network? Check the status of the file. Should be 200 else path is correct.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on that js folder?

Comment: @Teemu you were totally right :) Silly but still frustrating mistake. Feel free to type in your answer and I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Hmm ... there was a comment of mine here (now strangely removed), which encouraged you to post your own answer because you know the details better.

Answer (score 0):

It was the spy-blocker of the browser. Thanks @Teemu